# Difference of two arrays of objects with lodash

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, lodash

I have the following code inside my `useEffect` in reactJS

```
const A1 = [{id: 1, nome: "Ruan"}, {id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}]
const A2 = [{id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}, {id: 3, nome: "Geraldo"}]

const results = _.xor(A1, A2);

console.log(results)
```

The logic of `lodash` is `_.xor` is to return the difference between the two arrays, however, that is not what is happening

The return I get is as follows

```
0: Object {id: 1, nome: "Ruan"}
1: Object {id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}
2: Object {id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}
3: Object {id: 3, nome: "Geraldo"}
```

I appreciate all efforts to help

Comment: Its because object are not equal even if their contents are the same because they have different adresses in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xorBy` to indicate a property used for comparison:

```js
const A1 = [{id: 1, nome: "Ruan"}, {id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}]
const A2 = [{id: 2, nome: "Gleison"}, {id: 3, nome: "Geraldo"}]

const results = _.xorBy(A1, A2, 'id'); // or 'nome'

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because object are not equal even if their contents are the same because they have different adress in memory.

You can try something like this:

```
const results = _.xor(A1.map(object=> JSON.stringify(object)), A2.map(object=> JSON.stringify(object))).map(item => JSON.parse(item));
```