# How to filter array of objects in Lodash

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I have these objects:

```
var selectedItems = [
    { item:{ id:1, description:"Battery" }, quantity: 100 },
    { item:{ id:2, description:"Ballpen" }, quantity: 1000 },
    { item:{ id:3, description:"Can" }, quantity: 50 }
];
```

```
var optionSelection=[
    { id:1, description:"Battery" },
    { id:2, description:"Ballpen" },
    { id:3, description:"Can" },
    { id:4, description:"Bottle" },
    { id:5, description:"Glass" },
];
```

I want to find the optionSelection objects that are not present in the selectedItems.

Comment: You can get an idea from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64972447/1706467

Comment: And what have you tried... SO is not a get code for free site?

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: Sorry for that. I have tried a lot. this is what I've done recently.

`_.reject(this.customerItems,_.map(this.selectedItems,_.partialRight(_.pick,['item'])));`

by the way Im in vue.js 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`_.differenceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) to find the difference between the `id` fields.

```js
const selection = [
  { item: { id: 1, description: "Battery" }, quantity: 100  },
  { item: { id: 2, description: "Ballpen" }, quantity: 1000 },
  { item: { id: 3, description: "Can"     }, quantity: 50   }
];
const options = [
  { id: 1, description: "Battery" },
  { id: 2, description: "Ballpen" },
  { id: 3, description: "Can"     },
  { id: 4, description: "Bottle"  },
  { id: 5, description: "Glass"   },
];

// See: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith
const diff = _.differenceWith(
  options,
  _.map(selection, ({ item: id }) => id),
  (a, b) => a.id === b.id
);

console.log(diff);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is an ES5/6 version, without any dependencies.

```js
const defaultPluckFn = ({ item: { id } }) => id;

const filterOptionsBySelection = (
  options,
  selection,
  pluckFn = defaultPluckFn
) => (ids =>
  options.filter(({ id }) => !ids.has(id)))
(new Set(selection.map(sel => pluckFn(sel))));

const selection = [
  { item: { id: 1, description: "Battery" }, quantity: 100  },
  { item: { id: 2, description: "Ballpen" }, quantity: 1000 },
  { item: { id: 3, description: "Can"     }, quantity: 50   }
];
const options = [
  { id: 1, description: "Battery" },
  { id: 2, description: "Ballpen" },
  { id: 3, description: "Can"     },
  { id: 4, description: "Bottle"  },
  { id: 5, description: "Glass"   },
];

const filtered = filterOptionsBySelection(options, selection);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the `ids` of `selectedItems`, and then, filter out `optionSelection` items that are in it:

```js
const selectedItems = [
  { item:{ id:1, description:"Battery" }, quantity: 100 },
  { item:{ id:2, description:"Ballpen" }, quantity: 1000 },
  { item:{ id:3, description:"Can" }, quantity: 50 }
];
const optionSelection = [
  { id:1, description:"Battery" },
  { id:2, description:"Ballpen" },
  { id:3, description:"Can" },
  { id:4, description:"Bottle" },
  { id:5, description:"Glass" },
];

// get ids of selected items
const selectedItemIds = new Set( _.map(selectedItems, ({item}) => item.id) );

// get optionSelection items that are not selected
const res = _.filter(optionSelection, option => !selectedItemIds.has(option.id));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```